# .htaccess 301 Redirect - new domain is hosted in directory on old domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site at site.com.  It's moving to newsite.biz.

I log in to the hosting account for site.com and the directory tree is:
    directory-cgi-bin
    directory-newsite
    directory-wp-admin
    directory-wp-content
    directory-wp-includes
    all of the other Wordpress individual files such as wp-config.php wp-login.php etc. that go along with site.com

All of my newsite.biz files are in the newsite directory which is in the root of site.com I'm attempting to redirect all traffic from site.com to newsite.biz

Here's what I've tried:
Redirect 301 /how-it-works/ http://newsite.biz/how-it-works/
The error it says is too many redirects.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `I'm attempting to redirect all traffic from site.com to newsite.biz`

You should use mod_rewrite rule for better control:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.biz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Also make sure this rule is before other rewrite rules.